# Fritzbox behind a central Fritzbox: How to do internal call of phone on second fritzbox to phone on central fritzbox?

Tags: voip, phone, fritzbox

I have a central fritzbox and a second one with an attached phone. The configuration is done as described [AVM](https://at.avm.de/service/supportanfrage/produktauswahl/knowlegdebasesupport/detail/de_FRITZ-Box-3490-int/172_FRITZ-Box-zum-Telefonieren-ueber-andere-FRITZ-Box-einrichten/) and works in gerenal. But: 
**How can I do an internal call from that phone to a phone that is attached to the central fritzbox?**

I thought `*#**1` could work, if `**1` is the internal number of the phone attached to the cental fritzbox, but this gives a three tone signal and then a busy signal.

BTW: The other direction works. The `**1` can dial `**620` and reaches the other phone.

Comment: Are your two boxes in a mesh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it´s a question of a proper Fritzbox version.
If the second one was too old, it did not work. With Fritzbox WLAN 7360 it worked as expected and as described.